# Mouse Wrapping in Multi-Monitor Environments

Tags: c++, windows, mousemove

I've done a fair amount of research into this. There are programs, like Mousinity, which allow for "mouse wrapping". In case you know it by another term, that's when the mouse pointer will go off one side of the screen and appear on the other side of the screen.

However, all the programs that do this have failed to include one crucial element in their feature list: Multiple-Monitor set-ups. I am weary of downloading a completely alien piece of software only to have it not work with my set-up.

The down and dirty of this question is this:

Is there a way to control the behavior of the mouse pointer via some kind of API call for Windows? EDIT: More specifically, how does the API handle multiple monitors? Where is the origin for the coordinate plane?

While I do understand it will be much more complicated, here's my pseudocode for what I am trying to do:

```
if (mouse_position == side_of_screen_of_monitor1 && Mouse_is_being_moved off screen)
{    
    mouse_position == opposite_side_of_screen_of_monitor2
}
```

Comment: I will rephrase the question. I was actually looking more for information about how to deal with the mouse using C++. That is, using  whatever API would help deal with mouse-input on Windows. Re-reading my question, I see how that didn't come across as such.

Comment: You need SetWindowsHookEx() to set a low level mouse hook so you can see it move.  And EnumDisplayDevices() to find the monitors.

Comment: do not use SeWindowHookEx().  Thats old and out of date.  If you want to bring windows to its knees, write a low level hook, and set a breakpoint in it..  You should be handling raw input.  SendInput, register for input, etc.  This gives your application control over the input for the entire desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin is the top left corner of the primary monitor. If you have placed a monitor to the left of the primary monitor, the x-coordinates on that monitor will be negative. If a monitor is above or partially above the primary monitor, they y-coordinates will be negative in that area.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145136(v=vs.85).aspx

> GetSystemMetrics also has constants that refer only to a Multiple Monitor system. SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN and SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN identify the upper-left corner of the virtual screen, SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN and SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN are the vertical and horizontal measurements of the virtual screen

For more see here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162729(v=vs.85).aspx

For your task I think you probably only need to think about the virtual screen coordinates.